# What is the formula for calculating hit result score in Sunspot on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

Say, I have this code in my model:

```
class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
...
searchable do
  text :name
  text :facility_type do
end
...
```

And this in search controller:

```
 @search = Facility.search do
    keywords(query) do
      boost_fields :name =>  1.9,
                   :facility_type => 1.98
    end
    ...
```

And I have two Facility objects - first one having a type "cafe", but not having a word "cafe" in the name, a second one - called "cafe sun", for example, but being of a "bar" type in fact.

I run the search with query="cafe" and get both facilities in the response, but the score is 5.003391 for a "cafe sun" and 1.250491 for a real "cafe"

For the second try I set

```
boost_fields :name =>  1.9, :facility_type => 3
```

Score for "cafe sun" doesn't change, but "cafe" somewhat grew up - 1.8946824

So, as long as results get sorted by the score, I am interested how is it calculated ?

Or am I choosing wrong tokenizers or something, here is what I have in schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory"
            minGramSize="3"
            maxGramSize="30"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scoring results is the domain of the Lucene library, and the crux of its algorithm is described in detail here:

- http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html
- http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_1/scoring.html

To inspect the raw scoring data, run a query against your Solr instance directly and append the `debugQuery=on` parameter to see scoring data.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=test&defType=dismax&qf=name_text+facility_type_text&debugQuery=on
```

For general relevancy optimizations in Solr, you can consult the [SolrRelevancyFAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ). It also has one question specifically demonstrating [the output of `debugQuery`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#Why_does_id%3aarchangel_come_before_id%3ahawkgirl_when_querying_for_.22wings.22)

All in all: you ask a very good question with a very deep answer. I may edit my response down the road to expand on the subject.